# MSSQL, ASP.NET, IIS. SQL Server perfmon log question

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net

I'm testing a web application that runs on a hypervisor. The database server and the webserver are seperate vm's that run on the same hypervisor.
We did some tests and the functions perform ok. I want you guys to look at a screenshot of a permon log of the sql 2005 server on the busiest moment. The webserver perfmon log looks fine and it's obvious that we have enough resources to present the page in a timely fashion.

http://d.imagehost.org/view/0919/heavyload

http://d.imagehost.org/0253/heavyloadz.jpg

Zoomed out

The striped blue line maxing out is the Processor que length (scale 100,0)
The green line at around value 30 is Available MBytes (scale 0,01)
The rest of the counters are visible on the screenshot.

The sql server machine has no CPU limitations on the hypervisor resources and has 5 vcpu's and 5 GB RAM.

Can someone help me to interpret this log. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless I miss the colors... the SQL Server is overloaded. Too little memory and basically IO goes through the roof (slow discs). That said, I would rather download the logfiles and look at them in my own computer - I have serious problems identifying which line relates to what counter.

Comment: http://rapidshare.com/files/438752317/DataCollector01.blg

Comment: THe disk IO seems normal. Its the cpu activity that is a bit off.